# different precisions for numeric text depending on number value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I use knockout to show numeric value as following:

```
<td class="right"><span data-bind="numericTextWithoutNumericSeparator: Volume, precision: 4"></span></td>
```

In js file I have this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericTextWithoutNumericSeparator = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            precision = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().precision) || ko.bindingHandlers.numericText.defaultPrecision,
            formattedValue = value.toFixed(precision);

        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return formattedValue; });
    },
    defaultPrecision: 2
};
```

But I need to show numbers with 2 decimal digits if last 2 of 4 decimal digits are zero, otheriwse show numbers with 4 decimals.

Here is example:

```
1.1234 -> 1.1234
1.1200 -> 1.12
1.1350 -> 1.1350
1.0000 -> 1.00
```

How should I chande my js file to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
I edited my js file to this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericTextWithoutNumericSeparator = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            precision = function () {
                if (value % Math.round(value, 2) == 0) {
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    return 4;
                }
            },
            formattedValue = value.toFixed(precision);

        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return formattedValue; });
    }
};
```

But get rounding numbers up to 0 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`precision` is a function, but when you're calling it you've missed the parentheses

```
formattedValue = value.toFixed(precision());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
function shortNumber(number, precision) {
  var short = number.toFixed(precision)
  short = short + new Array(precision - short.split('.')[1].length + 1).join(0)
  return (short == number ? short : number)
}
```